# Android decode DTMF code coming from other phone

Tags: android, dtmf

I want to process DTMF code produced by other phone in real time. If one phone sends #1234 using [ToneGenerator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ToneGenerator.html) I want it to decode to #1234 in receiving app. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `AudioRecord` to record audio from the `VOICE_DOWNLINK` `AudioSource`, then perform a Fast Fourier Transform on the recorded audio to split it into different frequency "bins". From that information it's possible to guess if a given tone is being played (e.g. if there a lot of energy at a specific frequency but very little energy elsewhere in the frequency spectrum).

There's a [project at Google code called dtmf-decoder](http://code.google.com/p/dtmf-decoder/source/checkout) that attempts to do just this. I haven't used it myself so I have no idea of how well it works.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your response! I found jtransform to perform FFT. I will try your suggestion.